# Show that I watched on Cartoon Network, about teenagers who could transform to monsters

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

What I remember about the show is that some teenagers (3, I think) were some kind of monks that were able to transform through a device (I don't think that it was a power they were born with) into multiple monsters and could transfer monsters from each other.

I remember some good vs. evil stuff and that there were some tournaments between the group, I remember that one was in a desert for a powerful sceptre (?) and that the main antagonist had the monster that belonged to the main character's father before he died/disappeared and that the main character retrieved that monster during the tournament in the desert.

The cartoon was in English but, I watched the cartoon about 5 years ago but I think that it aired later in my country and I can't remember if it was airing for the first time or not.

Comment: Do you remember anything else? [There's a list](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) we have to help you add more details.

Comment: Possibly [Ben 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ben_10)?

Comment: Teenagers "transforming" into monsters? What was science-fiction or fantasy about it?

Comment: @User14111 - Badoom tish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it [Redakai: Conquer the Kairu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redakai:_Conquer_the_Kairu_(TV_series))?
It is almost exactly the same as what you described.
The main characters fight with magic and can transform into monsters using cards.

[image: Redakai cover photo]

Answer (score 6):

Could this be [Xaolin Showdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiaolin_Showdown)?

> Four young monks – Omi, Kimiko, Raimundo, and Clay – are forced into
>   cooperation at the Xiaolin Temple after learning they are chosen to
>   become Xiaolin Dragons. They become friends and work together
>   traveling the world in search for Shen Gong Wu, mystical objects with
>   powers that balance the forces of good and evil. Along the way, they
>   must battle wannabe evil boy genius Jack Spicer, and the evil Heylin
>   sorceress Wuya, whom Jack inadvertently frees from a 1500-year
>   imprisonment in a puzzle box by Grand Master Dashi. Through thievery,
>   Spicer ultimately possesses enough Shen Gong Wu to form Mala Mala
>   Jong, an ancient monster that Wuya uses to help her gain control of
>   the world. Raimundo defies orders and fights the monster, causing the
>   remaining monks to fight and defend the remaining Shen Gong Wu in the
>   Temple's possession. All the monks, except for Raimundo because of his
>   reckless disobedience, are promoted to Xiaolin Apprentices due to
>   their bravery. Angered, Raimundo joins the Heylin side and helps Wuya
>   regain her human form

Comment: It wasn't Xiaolin Showdown, or Chaotic. I remember quite nicely that the show had kids/teens changing into different monsters and that they were monks. I think that the monsters were card based and they definately could change between monsters.