# Cartoon about 3 kids on a spaceship that could turn into monsters from a device

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

This was a cartoon that had 3 kids, 2 boys and a girl, that used to be on a spaceship. Then there were alarms that there was that substance that they would go and scan with their phone-like devices and then they can turn into monster from that device and fight other people. The name of one the main characters was Kai, and I am pretty sure his name was a part of the name of the show.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  How long ago was it that you watched this?  Was it on TV?

Comment: It was around 2010-12 and it was on cartoon network as far as i remember

Answer (score 5):

This is a long shot, but could it be *The Hollow* (2018)? It is a Netflix Original, with one season so far.

There are three main characters, two boys and a girl: Kai, Adam, and Mira. In episode five, ["Ishibo"](https://www.netflix.com/watch/80148247), there is a spaceship.

<sub>all info from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hollow_(TV_series))</sub>

Comment: I'm not very sure about this, but the question has so few details I might as well try this as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Another option could be [Redakai: Conquer the Kairu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redakai:_Conquer_the_Kairu_(TV_series))

[image]

According to its Wikipedia article, the series was a Canadian/French animated series that premiered on YTV in Canada on July 9, 2011, on Cartoon Network in the United States on July 16, 2011 and on Canal J and Gulli in France on October 22, 2011.

The series revolves around Ky, a 15-year-old student of ancient martial arts, who embarks on an epic quest to find the Kairu, a primordial alien energy source. Aided by his friends Maya and Boomer, Ky travels the world searching for the Kairu while attempting to make sure that his extraterrestrial teenage alien adversaries don’t find it first.

(EDIT: Kudos to Bavnqta on [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/159713/show-that-i-watched-on-cartoon-network-about-teenagers-who-could-transform-to-m?rq=1) for giving me a tip-off it might be this)